# .bashrc alias help about terminal error

Tags: command-line, bashrc, alias, 20.10

i have alias on .bashrc file like;

```
alias modemreboot="IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }');echo "reboot" | sshpass -p "12345" ssh admin@$IP"
```

for to reboot my modem via command line. When i type or copy&paste to terminal it works, but as alias i get this error;

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting is messed up - as you can see by running the assignment with `set -x`:

```
$ alias modemreboot="IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }');echo "reboot" | sshpass -p "12345" ssh admin@$IP"
++ /sbin/ip route
++ awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
+ alias 'modemreboot=IP=via;echo reboot | sshpass -p 12345 ssh admin@via'
```

Try instead

```
alias modemreboot='IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk "/default/ { print \$3 }");echo "reboot" | sshpass -p "12345" ssh admin@$IP'
```

(although - unless your `/sbin/ip` is different from mine - I think you likely want `\$4` rather than `\$3`).

You may want to consider using a shell function instead, like

```
modemreboot () {
  local IP;
  IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
  echo "reboot" | sshpass -p "12345" ssh admin@$IP
}
```

See

- [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Comment: Thank you, shell function solved with &>/dev/null &